# GIMP Menu Font Issue?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, gimp

After installing GIMP in Kubuntu 18.04, the fonts in the menu are not so readable as seen in screenshot. How to change these menu fonts as per my suitability ? The fonts in previous version of gimp were fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find your theme (/usrs/hare/gimp/2.0/themes/) or equivalent in flatpak. The Theme contains two things:

- a `gtkrc` file
- lots of icons

Fonts (name/size/scale) are defined in the `gtkrc` file.

To be clean, you copy on of these themes to the Themes directory in your Gimp user profile, and point to that theme in `Edit>Preferences>Themes`, and edit the `gtkrc` to your heart's content.

Could be worth checking that Gimp isn't mistaken about your screen definition, though.